# In sqlite is it possible to cross-reference to a foreign Key

Tags: sqlite

I will apologise now coming from a c++ opp design pattern

For the example three table database (non-Key fields omitted) is it possible sane to cross-reference another table in the REFERENCES section?

```
CREATE TABLE `Attempt` (
    `attempt_ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `username`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `assessment_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(`username`) REFERENCES Students ( username ),
    FOREIGN KEY(`assessment_ID`) REFERENCES Assessments ( assessment_ID )
);
CREATE TABLE `Questions` (
    `assessment_ID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `question_number`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(assessment_ID,question_number)
);
CREATE TABLE "Responses" (
    `attempt_ID`    INTEGER,
    `question_number`   INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(attempt_ID,question_number),
    FOREIGN KEY(`attempt_ID`) REFERENCES Attempt ( attempt_ID )
);
```

The obvious solution is to include the assessment_ID in every question.row
but if we already know the attempt_ID then we can lookup the assessment ID ?

```
CREATE TABLE "Responses" (
    `attempt_ID`    INTEGER,
    `assessment_ID` INTEGER,
    `question_number`   INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(attempt_ID,question_number),
    FOREIGN KEY(`attempt_ID`) REFERENCES Attempt ( attempt_ID )
    FOREIGN KEY(`assessment_ID`,`question_number`) REFERENCES `Questions` ( `assessment_ID`,`question_number` )
);
```

Sub_Reference maybe ?

Comment: Upon further study of SQLITE foreign key constraints do not work across databases. Just in case anyone arrives here with a similar idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to want to do isn't "sane".

This is what you seem to want to do in the Response table.

```
FOREIGN KEY(question_number) 
    REFERENCES Questions(assessment_ID, question_number)
```

That's not "sane". (That's not SQL.) One column (question_number) cannot reference two columns (assessment_ID, question_number).

It's hard to say what you need to do to fix this. The difference between an attempt and a response isn't clear. If a response is a response to a question, then your Responses table should probably look something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE responses (
attempt_ID integer not null,
assessment_ID integer not null,
question_number integer not null,
primary key (attempt_ID, assessment_ID, question_number),
foreign key (attempt_ID) references Attempt (attempt_ID ),
foreign key (assessment_ID, question_number) 
    references questions (assessment_ID, question_number)
);
```

> The obvious solution is to include the assessment_ID in every
>   question.row but if we already know the attempt_ID then we can lookup
>   the assessment ID?

Whether you can find some way to navigate to the information you want isn't really relevant. In fact, this kind of thing is a problem that the relational model of data was developed to solve. Nowadays, we design databases based on functional dependencies and normalization.

Also, if you're designing a new database in SQLite, you probably shouldn't write the code using MySQL syntax.